# Multiple Google Charts on Same Page from same Data using Entity model

Tags: asp.net, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to setup a Web Page using the same data that is being pulled for the first chart. Data is being pulled by an edmx entity model. The code below works for single graph. I want to add a Pie Chart on the same page as well using the same data. All the examples I've seen are for graphs using static data. My code is below, I know I would need to just reproduce what I have in some fashion. Thanks,

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
  </script>
  @section Scripts{
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Load Data Here
        var chartData = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/GoogleChart/GetSalesData',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '',
            success: function (d) {
                chartData = d;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error!');
            }
        }).done(function () {
            drawChart(chartData);
        });
    });

    function drawChart(d) {
        var chartData = d;
        var data = null;
        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, {
            type: 'number',
            label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
            calc: function () { return 0; }
        }, {
            type: 'number',
            label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
            calc: function () { return 0; }
        }, {
            type: 'number',
            label: data.getColumnLabel(2),
            calc: function () { return 0; }

        }]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization1'));

        var options = {

        }

        var runFirstTime = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
            google.visualization.events.removeListener(runFirstTime);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });

        chart.draw(view, options);
    }

    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });

</script>

<div id="visualization1" style="width:900px; height:500px"></div>


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, recommend using...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

not...

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

note: the `load` statement will be the only difference, as seen below...

---

next, you can draw as many charts as necessary,
*after* the `load` statement has completed

you must set a `callback` to know for sure,
that google charts has loaded all of the requested `packages`...

multiple packages can be loaded at the same time

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: loadData,
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
});
```

[the callback](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#Callback) *will also wait for the document to finish loading...*

as such, `$(document).ready` isn't needed

---

recommend setup similar to following...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
@section Scripts{
<script>
  function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/GoogleChart/GetSalesData',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: '',
    }).fail(function (jq, text, errMsg) {
      console.log(text + ': ' + errMsg);
    }).done(function (jsonData) {
      drawCharts(jsonData);
    });
  }

  function drawCharts(jsonData) {
    var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

    var chartCol = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization-col'));
    chartCol.draw(chartData);

    var chartPie = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization-pie'));
    chartPie.draw(chartData);

    var chartTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('visualization-table'));
    chartTable.draw(chartData);
  }

  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: loadData,
    packages: ['corechart', 'table']
  });

</script>

<div id="visualization-col"></div>
<div id="visualization-pie"></div>
<div id="visualization-table"></div>
}
```

---

note: each chart has a specific [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format)

although most of the charts in `'corechart'` will be fine,
not all charts may work with the same data table...

Comment: also, to `runFirstTime`, you can use `google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener`...

Comment: works great, thank you, I'll continue to revise based on your recommendations.